# The appropriate way to query List from different variable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a table in which display many-to-many relationship. From the manager user, I will get a list of location that under manager management. Then from that list, I will get a list of user that related to those location. Here's my first implement to get location list

```
var locationManager = db.UserLocation.Where(x => x.userID == userID).ToList();
```

I don't know the appropriate to do the next step. Let's say manager's id is the userID with number 2. Therefor, the first line of code will return me with a list of UserLocation with userID = 2 which contain total of two locations with id of 1 and 2.
[Database table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgPAK.png)

In my mind, the next line of code to print out UserLocation would be like this but I don't want to hard code number 1 or 2.

```
var locationRelated = db.UserLocation.Where(x => x.locationId == 1 || x.locationId == 2).ToList();
```

Comment: If you have related tables then when you do your first call you should be about to get all data for example locationmanager.users.

Comment: You can avoid hard-coding the numbers 1 and 2, setting variables, says 'nb1','nb2', and querying db.UserLocation.Where(x => x.locationId == nb1 || x.locationId == nb2). You can get these variables from the UI or from a table, or whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Contains` to filter with collection:

```
var locationIds = new []{1, 2};// get ids somehow
var locationRelated = db.UserLocation
    .Where(x => locationIds.Contains(x.locationId))
    .ToList();
```

But it seems that there is typo, case you are querying `db.UserLocation` again. If you want to get `Location`(assume it is called like that), you can do that in one query, if your relations in enities are set up correctly:

```
db.UserLocation
    .Where(x => x.userID == userID)
    .Select(x => x.Location)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Actually I want to get all UserLocation with locationID equal with Userlocation with userID = 2

Comment: @Nobita then you original query ` db.UserLocation.Where(x => x.userID == userID).ToList()` should do the trick, what is wrong with it?